# Spark more tasks or more jobs

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, bigdata

I am building a Spark app which needs to run several Spark Jobs instead of running less Jobs but using more tasks.
Basically, my application runs N jobs formed by 1 task each instead of running 
1 Jobs formed by N partitions (tasks).

How does this design affect overall performance?